# touch() with java time

Tags: java, php, time, touch

I have a file and it should get a timestamp which I have as a Java timestamp in seconds since 1970.

I convert the Javatimestamp into php-timestamp:

```
$java_time = 1335997853142;
$php_time = $java_time / 1000;
$timestamp = date("d M Y G:i:s", $php_time);
```

Now I want to touch it to the file with the php-timestamp:

```
touch("test.txt", $timestamp);
```

But there the file date is changed to `01.01.1970 01:00:16`

`echo $timestamp;` returns `16 Jan 1970 21:48:21`

How to fix this?!

Comment: there is no "java timestamp" or "php timestamp". Time is independent of programming language

Comment: round the `$java_time/1000` when converting to `$php_time`

Comment: Yes but I want convert the second's timestamp to an useful timestamp.

Comment: rounding does not solve the problem...

Comment: Have you tried and debugged it? Is the value of `$php_time` correct for instance? If yes, then you know where the bug is...

Comment: `$php_time = substr($java_time,0, -3);`